# How to use AOS css library with ReactJS project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Fairly new to react, so I'm wondering if anyone can give me a sort of step-by-step rundown on how I can use AOS? I already did yarn add aos. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are referring to the AOS scroll library you have to import it and call it in the App.js file then call the init function :

```
 import Aos from 'aos';

function App() {
  Aos.init();
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

and for each element you want to animate you add one of the aos class names for example:

`<div data-aos="fade-down"> im a div </div>`

you can find more options for animations in the AOS documentation: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

**UPDATE**: you also need to import the AOS CSS like so:

`import 'aos/dist/aos.css';`